# how to pull the changes from main branch to forked branch?

Tags: git, github

How to pull the changes from the main repository to the forked repository?

**forked branch <- main branch**

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+update+forked+repository

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### step 1:

***Add upstream Git repository***

`git remote add upstream <PARENT_REPOSITORY_URL>`

#### step 2:

***Pull remote upstream branches***

```
git fetch upstream
```

#### step 3:

***Checkout to the local branch to update***

```
git checkout master
```

#### step 4:

***Merge the latest changes from the upstream Git repository***

```
git merge upstream/master
```

**Note:** Replace master in step3 and step4 with the branch you want to update.